# Syncfusion Grid : Not able to show Column Data as Link

Tags: angular, datagrid, syncfusion

I am working on Webapp which uses Syncfusion grid to show tabular data.
One of my requirement is to show a column data as link and call a function when user clicks on it.

I have gone through the tutorial provided by syncfusion  at [Syncfusion's official website](https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/gettingstarted/getting-started-webpack)

following way i am trying to achive the requirement as stated in documents :

```
 <e-column field="OrderID" headerText="Order ID" width="75" textAlign="right">
            <ng-template e-template let-data>
                    <div>
                        <a style="padding-left:5px !important;"> {{data.OrderID}} </a>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
```

But so far no success. Here is my package.json

```
"@angular/common": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/http": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~5.1.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"jquery": "~3.2.1",
"jsrender": "~0.9.84",
"syncfusion-javascript": "^15.4.17",
"ej-angular2": "^15.4.18"
```

Can anybody please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have achieved your requirement using ColumnTemplate feature of ejGrid. please refer the below code example.

```
// HTML File

<ej-grid [allowPaging]="true" [allowSorting]="true" [dataSource]="gridData">
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field="OrderID" headerText="Order ID" width="75" textAlign="right">
            <ng-template e-template let-data> 
                <div *ngIf="data.OrderID"> 
                    <a style="padding-left:5px !important;" (click)="clicked($event)">Click</a> 
                </div> 
                </ng-template>
        </e-column>
        ……..
    </e-columns>
</ej-grid>

// Ts File

export class GridComponent {
    public gridData: any;
    constructor() {
    ……………
    }
    clicked(e:any){
        alert("link column clicked"); // Do your stuff here.
    }
}
```

Refer to the demo sample [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/angular2-seeds-1487941912.zip)

Refer our help [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/grid/columns#column-template) for your reference

Comment: the template is not working at all.  I have imported only GRID component from the library from then the issue starts coming. Is there any dependency for column template ?